# Flashing Circle

Tags: css, animation, geometry

I made the circles that seems flashing

[image: Siren]

[image: Enlarged Circle behind the SIren]

I attached two pictures.
There's the siren as the pic1 and other circles that has different background color are positioned behind the siren as the pic 2.

I made it with CSS below.

```
 .box_siren_step1 {animation:alert_ani 2s infinite; -webkit-animation:alert_ani1 2s infinite;}
.box_siren_step2 {animation:alert_ani 2s infinite; -webkit-animation:alert_ani2 2s infinite;}
.box_siren_step3 {animation:alert_ani 2s infinite; -webkit-animation:alert_ani3 2s infinite;}
 .box_siren_step4 {animation:alert_ani 2s infinite; -webkit-animation:alert_ani4 2s infinite;}
@keyframes alert_ani4 {0%   {width:0px; height: 0px}  100%   {width:126px; height: 126px;}}
@-webkit-keyframes alert_ani4 {0%   {width:0px; height: 0px}  100%   {width:126px; height: 126px;}}
@keyframes alert_ani3 {0%   {width:0px; height: 0px}  100%   {width:116px; height: 116px;}}
@-webkit-keyframes alert_ani3 {0%   {width:0px; height: 0px}  100%   {width:116px; height: 116px;}}
@keyframes alert_ani2 {0%   {width:0px; height: 0px}  100%   {width:106px; height: 106px;}}
@-webkit-keyframes alert_ani2 {0%   {width:0px; height: 0px}  100%   {width:106px; height: 106px;}}
@keyframes alert_ani1 {0%   {width:0px; height: 0px}  100%   {width:96px; height: 96px;}}
@-webkit-keyframes alert_ani1 {0%   {width:0px; height: 0px}  100%   {width:96px; height: 96px;}}
```

Here's the HTML code for it.

```
   <div class="iu-box siren_wrapper siren_wrapper">
            <div class="iu-box box_siren box_siren_step4"></div>
            <div class="iu-box box_siren box_siren_step3"></div>
            <div class="iu-box box_siren box_siren_step2"></div>
            <div class="iu-box box_siren box_siren_step1"></div>
            <div class="iu-box box_siren box_siren_step0"></div>
          </div>
```

The problem is that,
CSS code looks fuzzy... Is there any other way to make it clear or simple?

Here's the JS Fiddle with this code.

http://jsfiddle.net/jooo/k1cenvx4

Comment: Why not use `box-shadow`?

Comment: are you looking for css formatting ??

Comment: @Richard um... I'll try the way to use box-shadow

Comment: @LokeshGupta I just want to find the other way to make the code be simple.